# How to map fields in a custom object to multiple columns in the db with JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I have a custom object:

```
@Embeddable
public class MyObject () {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    //getters and setters...
}
```

I have a persistence entity representing a table with two columns, I'll call them colA and colB. In the persistence entity I want to map field1 to colA and field2 to colB. I have tried:

```
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name="field1", column = @Column(name="colA", nullable=true)),
    @AttributeOverride(name="field2", column = @Column(name="colB", nullable=true))
})
private MyObject myObject;
```

But this fails to persist to the database when one of the fields does not have a value. I know AttributeConverter in JPA 2.1 allows us to persist multiple fields in an object to one column, but is there a way to persist two fields in an object to two different columns?

The errors I am getting at run time:

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(ComponentTuplizerFactory.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(ComponentTuplizerFactory.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.(ComponentEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentMetamodel.(ComponentMetamodel.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Component.buildType(Component.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Component.getType(Component.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.buildStandardProperty(PropertyFactory.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentMetamodel.(ComponentMetamodel.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Component.buildType(Component.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Component.getType(Component.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:290)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:464)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1362)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1865)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:906)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(ComponentTuplizerFactory.java:98)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: field [field1] not found on com.mypackage.persistenceentities.MyEntity
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor.getField(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor.getField(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:174)
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor.getGetter(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:197)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.getGetter(Property.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer.buildGetter(PojoComponentTuplizer.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer.(PojoComponentTuplizer.java:60)
    ... 25 more

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: I probably should have been a little clearer. MyObject is used in multiple persistence entities and the column names aren't always the same.

Comment: So, you want field1, field2, etc to be persisted on different tables under diff column names?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Do you have any control over the schema? This seems like you are bending the DB to do something that could easily be done with a joined table for `MyObject`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "this fails to persist to the database when one of the fields does not have a value". What happens precisely? If there is an exception, what's the complete stack trace?

Comment: so what is the table definition that is created for those entity annotations ? and what is the exception you get (+stack trace)?

Comment: MyObject is shared by dozens of persistence entities mapped to tables spread across multiple databases. Updating the schema isn't really an option as it will affect other applications.